# Brian was released without charge this evening after being detained

Tags: passive-voice, present-participles

1. Brian was released without charge this evening **after being detained** by police for about ten hours.
2. Brian was released without charge this evening, **being detained** by police for about ten hours.
3. **Being detained** by police for about ten hours, Brian was released without charge this evening.

Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Item 2 needs a comma, just like item 3.

Comment: I think #2 and #3 are invalid. Should be ***having been detained*** if you're not going to include ***after***.

Comment: @FF, Is it because the sequence of events is not clear?

Comment: Even when corrected as @FumbleFingers noted above, they don't mean exactly the same thing. That's because the word order creates a different emphasis. #1 emphasizes that he was released with the detention being secondary; #2/#3 emphasize the detention, with #2 doing so most strongly.